# Let's create a regular chat event!

Tags: discussion, chat-events

Now that we have our fantastic Community Bulletin, we can advertise our chat better and work in order to make this site more populated. So I was thinking: why not organize chat events? These ones would be on:

- Discussing site problems and strategies (e.g. promotion);
- Welcoming new users and helping them using the site;
- Etc...

But the question is... when? I think it's better if we decide a time and see where the most of us is availble. Alternatively, we can set two identical chat events for the same topic, one for a certain time zone, and another one for another time zone.

Chat events are easily scheduled in the chat, and you can register to the chat event (a click on a **Register** button is enough) so that you get a reminder before it starts.

Choose a Time Zone from this image that corresponds to your country and post it in the answer below:

[image: time zones image] ([Source](http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/2c.html))

Am I forgetting something? This meta question will be featured in the main site, be generous in your participation! :)

Comment: Has this died ?

Answer (score 5):

1. **Duration**: 1 hour (I think 1 hour is the least to achieve something.)
2. **Structure**:

   - First 15 minutes: welcoming new users or new "entries" in the regulars;
   - 35 minutes: we talk about the decided topics;
   - Last 10 minutes: recap and last-minute news.
3. **Some rules**: During these chat events, it'd be best if we kept the jokes/chit-chat to a minimum so we don't waste time and we *actually* solve problems. The usual rules abour proper behavior apply. :)
4. **Who**: Anyone can participate, and actually, I wish all of you would join the event. It'd be a huge victory towards our final goal: graduation and the creation of a great site of Linguistics.
5. **When**: Still to be done.
6. **Why**: Because if we don't do this for ourselves, no-one will do it for us.
7. **How**: We can either make the conversation-free OR organize it in a way that people talk  only after having requested the right to talk. The first one is more human and funnier I think, while the second is more organized but probably boring... I can do either. :)
8. **What**: These are some topics I think we could talk about (we choose some and do them in order or not):

   - **Promotion**: What have we done and what could we do? Is it enough? Strategies?
   - **Community Bulletin**: A quick overview of this new feature.
   - **Linguistics Community FAQ**: General discussion about its usefulness, etc.
   - **Users**: Proposals/criticism/anything from users about problems that might be present in the site (if any).
   - **Moderators**: Are you satisfied with their work? Anything you would change? Criticism? What about positive things? :)

Anything I forgot?

Comment: What would you suggest as topic(s) for the first chat?

Comment: Oh yes! I'll include that in the answer, @OtavioMacedo. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @OtavioMacedo Do you have anything to add?

Comment: No, I think that's good enough for the first event.

Comment: What time zone do most people live in? Might be useful in finding out when would be a good time to create this event.

Comment: @DangerFourpence How do you think we could do that? Maybe we can create a Wiki answer and everyone writes their timezone and we choose the biggest one?

Comment: @Alenanno I suppose so. Do you think there will be one or two big groups we can choose?

Comment: @DangerFourpence Probably, we need a way to confirm it, though... :) Check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

### User - Time Zone

> ***Note**: this is not a register form. It's here as a reminder for the time zones of those who want to participate.*

- Alenanno: +1
- Otavio: -3
- Danger: 0
- Tdhsmith: -6
- blunders: any timezone works