# #5 Linguistics Meeting

Tags: discussion, chat-events

Following the Meta discussion [Let's create a regular chat event!](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/351/111), let's post the necessary information for the next Linguistics Meeting.

> **Keep checking this post for updates!**
>
> *Want to read old meetings transcripts?* **[Check the list!](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/111)**

---

1. **Duration**: 1 hour
2. **Some rules**: During these chat events, it'd be best if we kept the jokes/chit-chat to a minimum so we don't waste time and we *actually* solve problems. The usual rules abour proper behavior apply.
3. **Who**: Anyone can participate, and actually, I wish all of you would join the event. It'd be a huge victory towards our final goal: graduation and the creation of a great Linguistics site.
4. **When**: Saturday, September 22nd, 16:00 UTC. [Check here for the time in your zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20120922T16).

   ### **[Register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1336/lgwstks?tab=schedule)**

   How do you do it? **1.** Visit the link above. **2.** Click on this! [image: register button] (Not here, of course. :P This is an image.)

   By registering, you'll get the reminders for the event, in case you intend to participate. Also, the corresponding time in your Time Zone is written there too.)
5. **How**: The meeting will be organized as a free conversation, but remember: be polite and don't make unnecessary noise, *the transcript will be saved!*
6. **Topics**:

   - ... *content is being added, you can propose new topics: post an answer!*