# FAQ: Can I propose a change in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq

I don't like something in the FAQ/I think something is missing in the FAQ, can I propose a change or a new addition to it?

How do I make sure it gets official? Are there standard procedures?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Of course you can!**

This is not a dictatorship, the site is being ruled by everyone, so you can propose a new change and try to include it in our official FAQ.

**How do you do that?**

It's simple: [ask a new Meta question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) tagging it [feature-request](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [faq-proposed](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). In this question, you'll need to ask the community what they think of your proposal. When you gain enough attention and a good number of people will agree with you, then a moderator will tag your question [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and it will be included in the FAQ.

If you need further elaboration fo your idea, you can still use your question or, better yet, partecipate in our [monthly Chat Meetings](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/111), also inviting your fellow users to support you in the discussion.